KVM: impossible to start default virtual network
I'm using KVM virtual machine on Debian 12 and I want to use the default virtual network.
First, the default network was missing
virsh net-list --all

so I reloaded it:
virsh net-define /usr/share/libvirt/networks/default.xml
virsh net-autostart default

virsh net-list --all
 Name      State      Autostart   Persistent
----------------------------------------------
 default   inactive   yes         yes

It worked but it's inactive. Now  when I try to start the default network:
virsh net-start default

I get these errors:

error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error: Network
is already in use by interface virbr0

How can I fix this ?

Can you update your question to show the output of virsh net-list --all?

@larsks I updated my question.
